# My Line-Of-Sight algorithm works, but I don't understand why

Tags: algorithms

I am developing a 3D application, and am currently [implementing a mutual visualization / Line-of-Sight algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MON7e.png). (Image from Mathworks.com)

What it is supposed to do is given two points, pA and pB, traverse the line and every few meters, check to see if that point is visible.

My algorithm for this is to get the distance from the starting point to the current point, and then get the difference in elevation between the two. I would compute the angle between these two points, and check it against the previous "highest angle"(or it would become the "highest angle" if there was not already one). If the angle were to be greater than the previous "highest angle", then that segment is visible and the angle becomes the new "highest angle". Otherwise, you cannot see that segment. This is repeated for every point along the line.

However, when testing this, it does not work. BUT, if I flip the comparison to be 'if the current angle is less than or equal to the highest angle, then you can see the point`, it does seem to work.

[My LOS algorithm visualized](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ev1oY.png)

So, why does it work? Visually, it does not make any sense. If the angle from P0 to P3 is less than the angle from P0 to P1, then the segment from P2 to P3 should not be visible. But, my code disagrees with me. I've attached some pictures for visual help.

Below is my algorithm written up in C++ (highestAngle is computed from p0 to p1)

```
for (std::size_t i = 1; i < pointsVec.size(); ++i)
    {
        Point p;
        p.m_x_lon = pointsVec.at(i).x();
        p.m_y_lat = pointsVec.at(i).y();
        GetPointElevation(p.m_x_lon, p.m_y_lat, p.m_z_elev);
        double dist = osgEarth::GeoMath::distance(std::vector<osg::Vec3d>{osg::Vec3d { start_xlon, start_ylat, 0 }, osg::Vec3d { p.m_x_lon, p.m_y_lat, 0 }});
        double newAngle = atan2(dist, p.m_z_elev - start_zelev) * 180 / M_PI;

        if (newAngle <= highestAngle)
        {
            highestAngle = newAngle;
            p.m_hasLOS = true;
        }
        else
        {
            p.m_hasLOS = false;
        }

        terrainProfileVec.push_back(std::move(p));
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having to check for a smaller angle doesn’t seem right to me, either. This is due to a bug in your code: the function `atan2` wants the $y$-value first, which here should be the elevation difference.

Note that you don’t need to compute the actual angles, which is a relatively expensive operation. It’s enough to compare slopes—tangents of the angles—which are just elevation difference divided by distance.

Comment: Ah, the initial value of highestAngle is the angle between p[0] and p[1]. Then in the for loop, I am going from p[1] to p[n-1]  points. I guess I should be going from p[2] to p[n-1] points.

I did not think about the slopes, I was too zoned-in on the angles. But it makes sense to use that, it'll be a lot less work on the CPU.
Should it matter if the endpoint is lower than the start point? Assuming the endpoint is sufficiently far enough away, it will be visible. Especially if it's going from the peak to a valley.

Comment: @Acorn Got it. That should be fine for an initial value. I also figured out your bug—see updated answer.

Comment: and so it is! I should really learn how to read math function parameters, instead of assuming it is always (x,y)...